# How to customize javascript array with space before each element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an issue with JavaScript arrays. I want a space after every array element. The elements are in lat,long form in side in inverted comma.
The data is available in this format:

[23.4343, 77.432342], [24.4343, 78.432342], [22.4343, 67.432342] and so on

data required in this format:

['23.4343,77.432342', '24.4343,78.432342', '22.4343,67.432342', '25.4343,68.432342', '33.4343,79.499342']

Comment: Is `[lat1, long1], [lat2, long2], [lat2, long2]` going to be array of arrays ? Like `var latLng = [[lat1, long1], [lat2, long2], [lat2, long2]];`

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = [ [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4] ];

var output = input.reduce(function(arr, val) {
  arr.push(val[0]); // For strings use `String(val[0])`
  arr.push(val[1]); // For strings use `String(val[1])`
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(output); // [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to format the array input as a string (which I assume is what you want?), you can iterate the array like this:

```
var test = [[23.4343, 77.432342], [24.4343, 78.432342], [22.4343, 67.432342]];

var result = "[";
for (var i=0; i<test.length; i++) {
    result += "'" + test[i][0] + "," + test[i][1] + "', ";
}
result = result.substring(0, result.lastIndexOf(", "));
result += "]";
```

This gives a result of:

```
"['23.4343,77.432342', '24.4343,78.432342', '22.4343,67.432342']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `[23.4343, 77.432342], [24.4343, 78.432342], [22.4343, 67.432342]` is `array of arrays`

```
var myarray=[[23.4343, 77.432342], [24.4343, 78.432342], [22.4343, 67.432342]];
var finalarray=[];
for(i=0;i<myarray.length;++i){
    var string='';
    for(j=0;j<myarray[i].length;++j){
        string+=myarray[i][j]+',';    
    }
    debugger
    string = '\''+string.substring(0, string.length-1)+'\'';

    finalarray.push(string);
}
alert(finalarray);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nz1o6gyn/)